# execute commands in pseudo terminal python

Tags: python, crash, automation, pexpect

I want to write a small script to automate some commands in python and linux. there is 'crash' utility in linux used to debug kernel cores and there are some sort of standard commands which I want to execute to save my time.

crash utility used pseudo terminal as similar to ftp. e.g ftp> crash>

I am aware about pexpect in the python but I would like to go with some other approach as if there is one change in behaviour or output then I need to change my whole script.

I am not sure if fork or some thing can be used for it. And I do not want to invoke crash prompt every time for each command to be executed.

Once I get data from the commands, I will write few condition to process further.

Thank you

Comment: It is not clear why you can't use `pexpect`. I can't understand your explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My intention behind not using pexpect is that for example if in linux we trigger 'free' or some other commands it will show some expected results and it would work fine, however if due to some patches or change in linux outputs, my script would be useless then.
For example in fedora earlier version 'free' output was showing something different and now no latest 22 its different. 
----------------------------
I want to write a script by which I can execure multiple commands in pseudo terminal and store their outputs somewhere.

Comment: Whatever solution you choose to execute arbitrary commands will depend on the output of these commands as well as `pexpect`. I still don't see why can't you use `pexpect` here. Unless there is API that avoids starting external processes and parsing their output; `pexpect` is the best option if you need a dialog based interaction with a subprocess that requires pty.